# r - retrieve only the first word and the following letter from a string

Tags: r

I'd like to retrieve only the first word and the following letter from a String. The situation is the following:

I have a column in my data frame where there is the first and last name of someone.

Example:

`FORD Mickael`

but I'd like to only have his last name and the first letter of his first name (`FORD M` in our example).

I only managed to get the first word from the string and not the following letter (using the word function from the stringr package).

Comment: You need to reproduce your data (rather than describing it) and include the code from your attempt to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
require(stringr)
x<-"FORD Mickael"
str_extract(x,"^\\w+\\s+\\w")
#[1] "FORD M"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tab <- data.frame(name = "FORD Mickael")
tab$name <- gsub("(\\w)\\w*$", "\\1", tab$name)
# [1] "FORD M"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
sub("[a-z]+$", "", x)
#[1] "FORD M"
```

#### data

```
x <- "FORD Mickael"
```